# Count weekdays between two dates and exclude dates from list

Tags: python, datetime, rrule

This code count the weekdays between two dates.

```
from dateutil.rrule import *
number_weekdays = rrule(WEEKLY, byweekday=(SU,MO,TU,WE,TH),
                        dtstart=datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 1),
                        until=datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 30)).count()
```

what should I do in order to exclude dates from a list ?

I know about  'exdate'  , but I dont know how to use it in this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import datetime 
from dateutil.rrule import *
rules = rruleset()

# all days to count
rules.rrule(rrule(WEEKLY, byweekday=(SU,MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA),
                        dtstart=datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 1),
                        until=datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 30)))

# exlude days from list
rules.exrule(number_weekdays)

rules.count()
```